# Is it possible to deploy ColdFusion code on Google App Engine for Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, coldfusion, bluedragon

Since ColdFusion is itself Java-based, I would imagine it's not too much of a stretch to suggest that CFML code could be deployed on Google App Engine.

BlueDragon is a commercial solution for deploying CFML code on Java servers.

Comment: I weep for google's servers :(

Comment: Is that a joke? You do know Coldfusion is quite efficient? It's basically a Java application server now with CFML as an extension language on top of Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's described in this thread how someone got OpenBD (Blue Dragon) running on App Engine:

[OpenBD on Google App Engine for Java](http://groups.google.com/group/openbd/browse_thread/thread/a9da36320b64d5d6)

Comment: It was Vince Bonfanti the creator of Blue Dragon that got it working on Google App Engine. Little tidbit.

Comment: actually Alan Williamson "created" BlueDragon Vince Bonfanti runs New Atlanta which bought the BlueDragon Servlet Engine.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any open source alternatives
>   that could be used for App Engine?

[Railo](http://www.getrailo.com/index.cfm/products/railo-open-source/) is another obvious candidate here, and some [people appear to be trying to tweak it](http://groups.google.com/group/railo/browse_thread/thread/1f2ce8522710fff1) for use on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I am putting together some demos that run on Open BlueDragon, which in turn is running on Google App Engine. The list is small at the moment, but eventually it should give you a good idea of what is opssible with OpenBD and GAE.

http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2010/05/12/cold-fusion-demos.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
http://www.stax.net/ - Stax networks made by a former Allaire(r)?

Works great, supports coldfusion out of the ..cloud.  You download a precompiled source file, put your stuff in, upload it and it all works, no fighting with it.

Answer (score 0):

I know google app engine is quite restrictive, it will involve opening up the source and removing everything that attempts to write to the file system, and changing your database interaction.

You can checkout [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/openbd/browse_thread/thread/a9da36320b64d5d6?pli=1) and group as a resource for [Open BlueDragon](http://openbluedragon.org/) as well as the [wiki](http://wiki.openbluedragon.org/wiki/index.php/Category:GoogleAppEngine).  Looks like they have a branch already which is working towards GAE compatibility.

On the [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org/) side of the CFML open source pond you can reference this article from help compiling Railo on your own [from the source](http://corfield.org/blog/index.cfm/do/blog.entry/entry/Building_Railo_from_Source).

Joining both of their respective google groups and asking questions should yield fruitful as well.

Good Luck!